# Building a dynamic javascript function with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know how bad this may look or what not, but here is what i need.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function foo(){
       //do stuff
       switch(name){
          case 1: 
          fun("123");
          break;
          case 2: 
          fun("123");
          break;
          @othercases.cshtml
       }
   }
```

and in othercases.cshtml it says

```
       case 3: 
          fun("123");
          break;
```

and this will add to the switch case on index.cshtml 
the reason i need this is because i want to be able to dynamically add cases through MVC. i do not want to display all cases to protect some customers information.

and thank you for your help.

Comment: In short, what you are trying to achieve won't protect any sensitive data... Once the partial or model property (depending on which method you use) renders, the JS it will be written to the response as if you had coded it directly into the view anyway. Is the problem you are trying to solve just, to protect sensitive data? Or is there something a little more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could use `Html.renderpartial("othercase")` and that did it. I encased that in an if block, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add the javascript code into the ViewBag or Model, and render it on the page through `@ViewBag.othercases` or `@Model.othercases` is the simplest conversion.  You can try `@Html.Action("othercases")` but that is probably overkill for something so simple.